# MongoDB Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory

Tags: mongodb, redhat

I am stuck with the following error while starting mongod service `systemctl start mongod`

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-27T20:48:20.219+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /var/lib/mongo"}}
```

I have already checked  `/var/lib/mongo` folder permissions and seem to be ok:

```
[root@**system]# ls -l / | grep var
drwxr-xr-x.  21 root   root   4096 Jun 25 07:43 var
[root@**system]# ls -l /var | grep lib
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root   56 Aug 27 20:38 lib
[root@** system]# ls -l /var/lib | grep mongo
drwxr-xr-x. 4 mongod mongod 4096 Aug 27 20:16 mongo
```

Any idea on why I am getting the error?

Comment: You have per-process filesystem overlays created by systemd which happen to be read-only?

Comment: Also check selinux and the security context.